# Improve execution of for cycle

Tags: bash, glob

I've done a small batch script to resize (on fly) some images:

```
for a in *.{png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,bmp,BMP} ;
do convert "$a" -resize $re "$re""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$re"].jpg" ; done
```

It runs.

Problem: if inside the dir there're only (an instance) **.png** files, the script runs but show me some errors because there are not other file extensions (**PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,bmp,BMP**)

What is the best way to improve it? redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`? any idea? I'd like to check (`$?`) exit status of script adding an if/then to show me if the script runs correctly.

Comment: What do you mean "runs correctly? Do you mean "converts any files"? Do you mean "every file conversion succeeded"? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two simple solutions off the top of my head.

Use the `nullglob` option to the [`shopt` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) so the non-matching globs disappear instead of remaining literal.

```
$ ls *.foo
ls: *.foo: No such file or directory
$ echo one *.foo two
one *.foo two
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo one *.foo two
one two
```

So your script would become.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for a in *.{png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,bmp,BMP} ;
do convert "$a" -resize $re "$re""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$re"].jpg" ; done
```

Or test for the existence of the file before using it with convert.

```
for a in *.{png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,bmp,BMP} ;
do [ -f "$a" ] && convert "$a" -resize $re "$re""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$re"].jpg" || :; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify why your script is not working as you expect as well as add another possibility just in case.

#### Why do you see that errors?

This is the general way to make a `for` loop:

```
for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
```

In your code, `word` is `*.{png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,bmp,BMP}`, and assuming you have only **.png** files, it expands as following:

- [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

  ```
  *.png *.PNG *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg *.JPEG *.bmp *.BMP
  ```
- [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

  ```
  file1.png file2.png *.PNG *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg *.JPEG *.bmp *.BMP
  ```
- **Example**:

  ```
  $ ls
  file1.png  file2.png
  $ echo *.{png,PNG,jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,bmp,BMP}
  file1.png file2.png *.PNG *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg *.JPEG *.bmp *.BMP
  ```

At this step, those are the strings you'll assign one by one to the variable `name`.
e.g.: `$name -> *.JPG`

---

#### Improving expansion with [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

As a first suggestion, you can use the `nocaseglob`:

> If set, Bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive fashion when performing filename expansion.

With this option, you can reduce `word` to `*.{png,jpg,jpeg,bmp}`

- **Example**:

  ```
  $ shopt -s nocaseglob
  $ echo *.{png,jpg,jpeg,bmp}
  file1.png file2.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp
  ```

  Or even `*.{PNG,jpg,jpeg,bmp}`

  ```
  $ echo *.{PNG,jpg,jpeg,bmp}
  file1.png file2.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp
  ```

---

At last, as [@Etan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) suggested, you can use the `nullglob` option:

> If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

- **Example**:

  ```
  $ shopt -s nullglob
  $ echo *.{png,jpg,jpeg,bmp}
  file1.png file2.png
  ```

---

As an alternative to `nullglob` in this case, you can use the `extglob` option (sometimes enabled by default):

> If set, the extended pattern matching features are enabled.

These are the [extended pattern matching features](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
?(pattern-list)
    Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
*(pattern-list)
    Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
+(pattern-list)
    Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
@(pattern-list)
    Matches one of the given patterns.
!(pattern-list)
    Matches anything except one of the given patterns.
```

So you can write `word` as `*.*(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp)`:

- **Example**:

  ```
  $ shopt -u nullglob
  $ shopt -s extglob
  $ echo *.+(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp)
  file1.png file2.png
  ```

In this way, it is all expanded in the [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) step.